# How do I give the permission to add points, but not to moderate them?

Tags: 6, users, userpoints

When I give users the permission to administer user points, they can both add and moderate points. How do I give them only the permissions to add points, but give other users the permission to moderate points?

Can someone tell me how to use the `hook_menu` stuff, to set permissions? My email is lucas.famelli@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 6, there is no easy way to do that. It might work if you implement `hook_menu_alter()` in a custom module and add a different permission in access arguments that the default.

It might not help you at this point, but I have taken over that module for Drupal 7 and we have improved it *a lot*. Among many other things, it now has separate add/edit and moderate permissions which allow for fine-grained access control. So if you are just starting your site, you might want to consider using Drupal 7 instead.

Comment: I can't do that, it's already done and in production... Can you give me some more info on how to do that `hook_menu_alter()`?